# AFURLSessionManager free memory after data upload

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsdata, afnetworking-2

I´m trying to split a big local file into separate NSData parts and then upload each file part using AFNetworking 2. After all uploads succeed the data for each file part is still in memory. How do I free memory after each finished part upload? What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
-(void) uploadRequestWithPart:(FilePart*) part{
    // setup request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:part.uploadURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request setValue:part.fileType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"private" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-amz-acl"];

    if(!sessionManager) sessionManager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSProgress *progress = nil;

    // create Data from file part
    FILE *file = fopen([part.fileURL.path UTF8String], "rb");
    if(file == NULL) return;
    void *data = malloc(part.size);
    fseeko(file, part.offset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(data, 1, part.size, file);
    fclose(file);

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *upTask;
    upTask = [sessionManager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:part.size] progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
            [upTask cancel]; // <- does cancelling this task release the NSData??
            upTask = nil;
        } else{
            NSLog(@"Upload complete");
            [upTask cancel];  // <- does cancelling this task release the NSData??
            upTask = nil;
        }
        [progress removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"partCompleted" context:nil];
    }];
    // setup upload progress
    [progress setUserInfoObject:part forKey:@"part"];
    [progress addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"partCompleted" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    // start upload
    [upTask resume];
}
```

Thanks, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

dataBytesNoCopy:length: creates a NSData wrapper around the file part buffer. The resulting NSData object is responsible for freeing the data buffer. Since there are multiple approaches to get a chunk of bytes from a file I tried this (which works for me):

```
...
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:part.fileURL.path options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];
NSData *partData = [fileData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(part.offset, part.size)];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *upTask;
upTask = [sessionManager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:partData progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {...
```

This way ARC takes care about freeing the byte data. I hope this helps someone.